# How can I make this specific area have the black material?

Tags: materials, edges

I can't make an edge loop here, but I want the black strips from both of those sides to carry onto the top on both sides of the model. I don't know how to make that happen and I'm not extremely advanced when it comes to blender. This explanation was probably terrible but hopefully the annotation in the picture can explain better[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could fix it but maybe the best is to start correctly, which means create a circle:

[image]

Inset with <kbd>i</kbd>:

[image]

Join the 2 opposition vertices with <kbd>J</kbd>:

[image]

Delete the bottom half:

[image]

Extrude down:

[image]